# How to make Level as per total no?

Tags: android

> Hello  I want to separate level no as per total no. E.G I want result
>   like if total no is 27 then  if no is between 1-9 then level no = 1, 
>   if no is between 10-18 then level no = 2,  if no is between 19-27 then
>   level no = 3. Here total no is anything but part is same 9 no in each
>   part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with below calculation

```
float no = your value;
float result = (float) (no / 9.0);
```

Take the value which is before `Decimal Point` to get your **Level Number** from `result`

Hope this helps.